# Нужно ли выделять запятыми номера этапов при описании порядка выполнения действия?

Tags: пунктуация

Например:
На первом этапе 1 выполняют ...
На следующем этапе 2 регистрируют ...

и т.п.

Нужно ли в подобном случае выделять цифры запятыми как уточнение?

Answer (score 1):

Цифра не должна дублировать порядковое числительное, как и слово *этап* не должно сопровождать перечисление: цифра, заключённая в скобках, и есть условный номер этапа.

Оператор (1) выполняет..., (2) регистрирует ... и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Цифры не выделяются запятыми.

В качестве варианта можно использовать скобки:

На первом этапе (1) выполняют ... На следующем этапе (2) регистрируют ...